# Method to calculate the average without storing individual values

Tags: swift

```
struct someStruct {
    //...
    var rating: Double
    mutating func rate(rating: Double) {
    }
}
```

I know how to calculate the average if I record every rating in an array. But my idea is to modify the `rating` each time I call the method `rate()` with a new `rating`, just like

```
self.rating = (self.rating * numberOfRatings + rating)/(numberOfRatings + 1)
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to manage `numberOfRatings`. How can this be realized specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make `numberOfRatings` a property of your structure:

```
struct someStruct {
    //...
    var rating: Double = 0
    var numberOfRatings: Double = 0
    mutating func rate(rating: Double) {
        self.rating = ((self.rating * numberOfRatings) + rating) / (numberOfRatings + 1)
        numberOfRatings++
    }
}
```

Then you'd use it like this:

```
var a = someStruct()

a.rate(5)
a.rate(6)
a.rate(8)
println(a.rating)  // prints "6.33333"
```

---

@ABakerSmith provides an alternate answer that has the advantage of maintaining the `total` which avoids introducing error into the calculation.  We can take that a step further and turn `rating` into a computed property that only gets calculated when you need it:

```
struct someStruct {
    var total: Double = 0
    var numberOfRatings: Double = 0
    var rating: Double {
        return total/numberOfRatings
    }

    mutating func rate(rating: Double) {
        total += rating
        numberOfRatings++
    }
}
```

This would be more efficient if you call `rate` more often than you access the `rating` property.  If the opposite is true, then computing the `rating` within `rate` would be more efficient.

Comment: Nice idea! One thing, I don't think you need to write `get` in the computed property. Doesn't not giving a setter already make it read-only?

Comment: Indeed, @ABakerSmith.  Removing the `get` will make it cleaner.

Comment: I don't quite understand the last two sentences. What is the difference between calling a stored property and computed property?

Comment: The computed property will compute the result every time you access it.  If you access `rating` much more often than you call `rate`, then it would be more time efficient to compute the rating and store it when you call `rate`.

Answer (score 0):

@vacawama gives a good method. Here's an alternative you could try too: firstly, have a look at [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1627-create-a-running-average-without-storing-individual-values.htm). The there are two methods stated at the end for calculating a running average. The simplest one is to add the *n*th number to the existing total and divide by *n*. Here's an example:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    var rating: Double = 0
    var numberOfRatings: Int = 0
    var total: Double = 0

    mutating func rate(num: Double) {
        total += num
        rating = total / Double(++numberOfRatings)
    }
}
```

Then use this like so:

```
myStruct.rate(5)
myStruct.rate(6)
myStruct.rate(8)
myStruct.rating // 6.33333...
```